# What language+libraries could I use to parse a CSV/Google Sheets file and then send text messages using some of the parsed info?

Tags: python, java, software-development, automation, csv

The goal is to send the same message to many people (volunteering reminders) but in an automated fashion. The only difference between messages would be the name at the beginning and the target phone number, which would come from a CSV file or Google Sheets directly.

Languages I would be comfortable using (in order):

- Java
- Python
- JavaScript
- Something new and not too hard to pick up

The end goal would be click a few buttons (convert Google Sheet to CSV, add to a folder, run a `.cmd` command) and then everything is sent out within 5 minutes from a personal phone.

A sample CSV file would be:

```
Bob,5555555555,other unimportant information 
Dave,6666666666,other unimportant information
...
```

Message:
`Hi Bob/Dave, We have a volunteer event on Thursday. Can you make it?`

This would be on Windows 10, probably 8 GB of RAM or more. Let me know if any more details would be helpful.

Comment: Use Twilio to send text message using an API. https://www.twilio.com/

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script has Spreadsheet Service, Mail Service and  Gmail Service and also could easily enable the use of the Google Sheets API so parse data from Google Sheets and to send emails.

Also it has HTML Service to create a custom dialog or even a web application as simple as a web page having a couple of buttons and using well known front en libraries like Bootstrap.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script

Comment: The title asks for text messages, which I guess means SMS ?

Comment: In such case my this is a partial answer address the first part of the question (parse a CSV or Google Sheet) and the third part, creating a user interface.

Comment: Text messages could be achieved through SMS gateways, the trick is knowing the provider, the good news is that sending to non existent addresses generally just fails silent. a good list here. https://avtech.com/articles/138/list-of-email-to-sms-addresses/  we generally target the major providers number@providergateway(s) and get an extremely high delivery rate.